# Why do I get NaN from I function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple JavaScript program that converts celsius to fahreinheit and vice versa. But one function does not work and returns NaN.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CtoF() {
        c = parseInt(document.getElementById("celsiusTemp").value);
        fah = c * (9 / 5) + 32;
        document.getElementById("resC").innerHTML = fah;
    }

    function FtoC() {
        f = parseInt(document.getElementById("celsiusTemp").value);
        cel = (f - 32) * (5 / 2);
        document.getElementById("resF").innerHTML = cel;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        <p>Insert celsius temperatur:
            <input type="text" id="celsiusTemp" />
            <br>
        </p>
        <p>Insert fahrenheit temperatur:
            <input type="text" id="fahreheitTemp" />
            <br>
        </p>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" onClick="CtoF()" Value="Calc Fahrenheit" />
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onClick="FtoC()" Value="Calc Celsius" />
    </form>
    <br/>
    <p>The Result is :
        <br/>
        <p>Result celsius to fahreinhet:</p><span id="resC"></span>

        <p>Result fahreinhet to celsius:</p><span id="resF"></span>

</body>
```

Why do I get NaN when calculating celsius)

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably meant `getElementById("fahreheitTemp")` in your `FtoC` function...

Comment: Where do you get NaN? Why are you using different ratios for conversion in the two different formulas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably need to replace:

```
f = parseInt(document.getElementById("celsiusTemp").value);
```

With:

```
f = parseInt(document.getElementById("fahreheitTemp").value);
```

If you click the `Calc Celsius` button, it will try to get a value from the Celsius field. If that's empty, the `parseInt` will return `NaN`:

```
isNaN(parseInt("")) === true
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your celsius function is reading the wrong input, and since you haven't typed into that input when you test the function, it is an empty string which `parseInt` turns into Not A Number.